# Temperature sensor and web server flooding

Tags: security, http, web-applications, arduino

I cannot find a good answer to my situation.

I have some temperature sensors (Arduinos) sending data to my webserver with a GET HTTP request.

On each request, temperature is stored in database with the sensor's id and the date.

Now, I am a bad guy and I detect the GET request's structure. And I do a bunch of those GET requests to flood the webserver (worst case) or record bad temperature data (slighty better case).

How do I prevent this?

I am thinking of defining a unique secret number to the sensor and to "authenticate" it through a POST request... but how to achieve this? How would the number not be stolen during the request?

Any reading to suggest?

Comment: If the problem is that you are a bad guy, the simplest solution is to become nicer :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can :

1. use a key to hash the whole or sensitive part of the transaction so only the correct key can decode the request back on the server. You'll be able to tell phonies from genuine request.
2. It is always good to limit the number of request the server can accept during a time frame, from one sensor, this will protect it against DOS and flooding.
3. Keep track of the sending IP's addresses. You'll be able to tell good IP's from the bad ones

Some reading on encryption for arduinos:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355/encryption-libraruy-for-arduino

Comment: I like the #3, simple and obvious. Maybe not that secure, but with a time limit between two requests of the same IP I should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate each request with a secret key.

Use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) over SHA-256 to create a hash of the parameters.

e.g. if your secret is `password1` and your GET parameters are `sensorId=123&temperature=21` you calculate your SHA-256 hash over these.

```
HMAC("password1", "sensorId=123&temperature=21")
```

[this gives](http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html) `75e9ad4ebfa22b2fca2f4bb24d23b56e6f6d32aa285bcc84f42a3116a7e02b6a`, which makes your GET request now have the following query string:

```
sensorId=123&temperature=21&hash=75e9ad4ebfa22b2fca2f4bb24d23b56e6f6d32aa285bcc84f42a3116a7e02b6a
```

You can validate that these values using the same secret key give the same hash on the server, mitigating any tampering.

TLS is recommended (i.e. https) as this mitigates any replay attacks and will help your URL format from being determined by an eavesdropper. You might also want to add in a date and time field which you also calculate the hash over to prevent an attacker that can see the raw format from replaying the GET request.